# row heights in jxls-2 templates using for-each statements

Tags: excel, jxls

We have an issue with row heights using for-each statements in jxls v2.
The height of a single line for-each template row is not populated to all item rows in the resulting xlsx. In fact, row heights rather seem to depend on the row height of the same (static) row number in the template. We have created a simple example using the `ObjectCollectionDemo` demo (http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/object_collection.html) from the website with a modified template:

https://portal.atesio.de/owncloud/index.php/s/lHFcEjcpr5Rs1W5

Applying the template we observe that the rows in the first collection strongly differ in height.

(Also the red frame seems not be set correctly.)

Are we doing something wrong?

Thank you and all the best, 
     Christian Raack

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.

I have created an [issue-45](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/45/incorrect-row-height-is-set-in-each) for it and will update this answer when it is resolved.

**Update 1:**

There is an easy workaround for this issue. 
Just modify the template to have Each-commands include the frame border as shown on the screenshot below and it will work as expected

[image: modified template]

**Update 2:**

The issue is now resolved in 2.3.0 version.
Check [Jxls home](http://jxls.sf.net) for the latest updates.

Comment: You are right. Changing and Moving the Each-commands resolves the issue with the row heights. It is not very intuitive ;) but will work for us as long as there is no update. Thank you Leonid!

Comment: In fact, there might be a conceptional problem here. What happens for instance if we have two for-each statements in the same row and a different number of items in the two collections?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Please if you have a real case please add all the necessary info to the mentioned ticket above or create a new one.